# Count of orders based on other columns departmentwise in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, oracle12c

I have one table with deparment, orders,datum,clerk and status. There are 3 clerks in each department, for simplicity I show just one department.
Rick is tier 1
Simon is tier 2
Tom is tier 3

each order is processed one or more time that means it can be approved directly in one step by all tiers but sometimes th order is being checked more than once ( by the same clerk as well ) and goes in the next tier. Some orders are special and must be approved at least in the tier 2 therefore Rick didn't check/approve (order3 in this case)

the goal is to find out  how many orders has been approved by each clerk departmentwise but not just the total count. i need to distinguish between orders approved in single step by the clerk which approved the order and orders that has been processed and approved by the same clerk more than 1.

[image]

the output should look like this, as you see Tom approved 2 orders in single step (order1 and order3) and order3 in two steps. Simon has 2 orders in single step and Rick has just one order that was processed by him twice.

[image]

there are two more columns
No. of orders without tier 1, the ordere
No. of orders without tier 2 but approved by tier 3, valid orders are order2 and order 6

Comment: How are you calculating the last 2 columns? Also I see you have not accepted answers for any of your questions. If you find any answers that solved your problem, you should mark it as resolved. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Hi I would accept the answer but I don't see anu button for that. to you queston. number of orders without tier 1. Rick is tier 1 so you look uporders without Rick. the last column Simon is tier 2 so you do the same, orders where there is no Simon but such orders must by approved byt tier 3 (Tom)

Answer (score 1):

1. Within subquery "t" I use lag analytic function to get the previous clerk, and  listagg analytic function to get a list of clerks by orders column value
2. Then in the outer most query "tt", I make a group by dep, and then I make many many counts columns as there are in the desired output.

It is important to use `decode(status, 'approved', 'zzzzzzzz', status)` to make your order by clause in analytic functions deterministic here. there may be tied datum column values by orders (e.g. orders = 'order5').

```sql
select tt.DEP
, count(case when clerk = 'Rick' and (prev_clerk != clerk or NB_STEPS = 1) and status = 'approved' then orders end ) "orders in single step by Rick"
, count(case when clerk = 'Rick' and prev_clerk = clerk and status = 'approved' then orders end ) "orders processed >1 by Rick"
, count(case when clerk = 'Simon' and (prev_clerk != clerk or NB_STEPS = 1) and status = 'approved' then orders end ) "orders in single step by Simon"
, count(case when clerk = 'Simon' and prev_clerk = clerk and status = 'approved' then orders end ) "orders processed >1 by Simon"
, count(case when clerk = 'Tom' and (prev_clerk != clerk or NB_STEPS = 1) and status = 'approved' then orders end ) "orders in single step by Tom"
, count(case when clerk = 'Tom' and prev_clerk = clerk and status = 'approved' then orders end ) "orders processed >1 by Tom"
, count(case when list_clerk_by_orders not like '%Rick%' then orders end) "orders without tier 1"
, count(case when clerk = 'Tom' and status = 'approved' and list_clerk_by_orders not like '%Simon%' then orders end) "withouttier2_approved_in_tier3"
from (
  select t.*
  , count(*)over(partition by orders)nb_steps
  , lag(clerk, 1)over(partition by orders 
        order by datum, decode(status, 'approved', 'zzzzzzzz', status))prev_clerk
  , listagg(clerk, ', ')within group(order by datum, decode(status, 'approved', 'zzzzzzzz', status))over(partition by orders)list_clerk_by_orders
  from test_table t
)tt
group by tt.DEP
;
```

sample

```
create table test_table (dep, orders, datum, clerk, status) as 
select 'ABC', 'order1', to_date('27.8.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Rick', 'checked 1' from dual union all
select 'ABC', 'order1', to_date('4.9.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Simon', 'checked 2' from dual union all
select 'ABC', 'order1', to_date('11.9.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Tom', 'approved' from dual union all

select 'ABC', 'order2', to_date('27.8.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Rick', 'checked 1' from dual union all
select 'ABC', 'order2', to_date('4.9.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Tom', 'approved' from dual union all

select 'ABC', 'order3', to_date('11.9.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Simon', 'approved' from dual union all

select 'ABC', 'order4', to_date('17.9.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Rick', 'checked 1' from dual union all
select 'ABC', 'order4', to_date('25.9.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Rick', 'approved' from dual union all

select 'ABC', 'order5', to_date('17.9.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Rick', 'checked 1' from dual union all
select 'ABC', 'order5', to_date('25.9.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Rick', 'checked 2' from dual union all
select 'ABC', 'order5', to_date('29.9.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Simon', 'approved' from dual union all

select 'ABC', 'order6', to_date('25.9.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Rick', 'checked 1' from dual union all
select 'ABC', 'order6', to_date('30.10.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Tom', 'checked 2' from dual union all
select 'ABC', 'order6', to_date('31.10.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Tom', 'approved' from dual
;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems we can look at the order as a whole, rather than iterating through the rows: Has Rick approved without a check #2? Has Rick done a check #2 at all? ... This is a mere aggregation, albeit with conditional aggregation and in two steps:

1. Get the statuses per order. (I am doing this with creating flags with 1 = true, 0 = false.)
2. Get the overall counts. (I am doing this by summing up the flags.)

The query:

```
select
  sum(single_step_rick),
  sum(processed_twice_rick),
  ...
  sum(without_tier_1),
  sum(approved_without_tier_2)
from
(
  select
    order_id,
    case when 
      count(case when clerk = 'Rick' and status = 'approved' then 1 end) > 0
      and
      count(case when clerk = 'Rick' and status = 'checked 2' then 1 end) = 0
    then 1 else 0 end as single_step_rick,
    case when 
      count(case when clerk = 'Rick' and status = 'checked 2' then 1 end) > 0
    then 1 else 0 end as processed_twice_rick,
    ...
    case when
      count(case when clerk = 'Rick' then 1 end) = 0
    then 1 else 0 end as without_tier_1,
    case when
      count(case when clerk = 'Tom' and status = 'approved' then 1 end) > 0
      and
      count(case when clerk = 'Simon' then 1 end) = 0
    then 1 else 0 end as approved_without_tier_2
  from orders
  group by order_id
);
```

Comment: I modified the case ,correct me if I am wrong. you have incorrect Sums but nice approach as well   case when 
      count(case when clerk = 'Rick' and status = 'approved' then 1 end) > 0
      and
      count(case when clerk = 'Rick' and status <> 'approved' then 1 end) = 0
    then 1 else 0 end as single_step_rick,
   case when 
      count(case when clerk = 'Rick' and status = 'approved' then 1 end) > 0
      and
      count(case when clerk = 'Rick' and status <> 'approved' then 1 end) > 0
    then 1 else 0 end as processed_twice_rick

Comment: I thought that when I look at a ticket and it has been approved by Nick, but there is no 'checked 2' for Nick, then he has approved it without check 2, hence in one step. Your alteration, however, indicates that one step means 'approved' without any other status, not even 'checked 1'. You know your data better than I, so I was probably wrong and you are right.

Comment: I also thought that 'checked 2' means processed twice. But your alteration indicates that "processed more than once" means accepted plus at least one other status for you. And again: you know the rules that apply, I was only guesstimating :-)

Comment: Hi, no problem, your approach is different from MDO, I can use it as well with my modification of course, 1 go means that the clerk which approved the order must be there just 1x so he checked and approved at the same time therefor only the approved status is there- 1 date but there are situation when the same clerk checks on one day but approves on another , hence it is not treated as 1 go(step)